# Cannot open/view/grab/read IP Camera using OpenCV

Tags: java, macos, opencv, camera

I am using OpenCV to grab an IP Camera's stream and frames. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.videoio.Videoio;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.*;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Size;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String newCameraIP  = "http://10.12.18.11/mjpg/video.mjpg";
    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();
    if (cap.open(newCameraIP)) {
        System.out.println("Camera opened from " + newCameraIP);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No camera found at " + newCameraIP + ". Trying USB ports...");
    }
```

USB cameras work fine but when I try to use an IP Camera, I receive the following error message: 
**VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!**

Comment: What makes you think `VideoCapture` knows anything about URLs?  AFAICT the C++ and Java APIs can only open local files.  You'll have to download the data first.

Comment: @JimGarrison that actually explains a lot... How would I go about downloading the data? Would I do that within my code or separately? What about using OpenCV with ffmpeg support? p.s. I need to do this in real-time as I'm using this for vision processing.

Comment: `cvCreateFileCapture` (with ffmpeg libraries available) works with URLs. Just checked at http://www.smartec-cctv.ru/docs/certificate/4-Compare_VMD_and_VCApresence_tracking_performance.wmv

Comment: @MBo do you think that error is related to the ffmpeg libraries?

Comment: `AVFoundation` resembles something from ffmpeg. Have you tried to use this camera from  another software (like VLC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this exact problem using Python on OSX. The solution for me was to rebuild opencv using the --with-ffmpeg flag.